# Switch in SELECT in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to use something like "switch" to define the new column in result.

Example:

```
-----------------------
user_id | nick | role |
-----------------------
   1    | dupa |   A  |
   2    | geno |   U  |
   3    | mato |   E  |
-----------------------
```

Since A means "administrator", U means "default user" and E means "editor", I need to put new column to result and get the fullname of role. Something like this:

```
----------------------------------
user_id | nick | role | fullname |
----------------------------------
   1    | dupa |   A  |   admin  |
   2    | geno |   U  |   user   |
   3    | mato |   E  |  editor  |
----------------------------------
```

So it seems I need to use Switch, because there are more than 2 roles. If role = 'A', then fullname will be admin, and so on. How can I do that?

I have something like this for now:

```
SELECT
    user_ud, 
    nick, 
    role, 
    CASE
        WHEN role = 'A' THEN fullname = 'Admin' 
        WHEN role = 'E' THEN fullname = 'Editor'
        WHEN role = 'U' THEN fullname = 'User'
        ELSE fullname = NULL
    END
FROM 
    [tablename] ...
```

But it doesn't work :(

Comment: You got plenty of answers, for future questions though: if something doesn't work, explain what doesn't work. Does it throw an error? If so, what is the error. Is the output unexpected? If so, what do you expect, and what do you actually get.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign column values in a `CASE` expression. Just return the values you want and assign an alias to the expression:

```
SELECT
    user_ud, 
    nick, 
    role, 
    CASE
       WHEN role = 'A' THEN 'Admin' 
       WHEN role = 'E' THEN 'Editor'
       WHEN role = 'U' THEN 'User'
       ELSE NULL
    END as fullname
FROM [tablename] ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    user_ud, 
    nick, 
    role, 
    (
        CASE
            WHEN role = 'A' THEN 'Admin' 
            WHEN role = 'E' THEN 'Editor'
            WHEN role = 'U' THEN 'User'
            ELSE NULL
        END
    ) AS fullname 
FROM [tablename]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    user_ud, 
    nick, 
    role, 
CASE role 
    WHEN 'A' THEN 'Admin' 
    WHEN 'E' THEN 'Editor'
    WHEN 'U' THEN 'User'
    ELSE NULL
END as fullname 
FROM [tablename]
```

Answer (score -1):

Wrong syntax and NULL is default, can be omitted.

```
fullname = CASE
  WHEN role = 'A' THEN  'Admin' 
  WHEN role = 'E' THEN  'Editor'
  WHEN role = 'U' THEN 'User'
END
```

When all predicates are `=` you can use alternative syntax

```
fullname = CASE role
  WHEN 'A' THEN 'Admin' 
  WHEN 'E' THEN 'Editor'
  WHEN 'U' THEN 'User'
END
```